# SAPRFC DLL and PHP 5.5

Tags: php, dll, saprfc

I wanted to try using SAPRFC DLL along with PHP to retrieve data from SAP server at our company, but after downloading the latest version (1.4.1) from `http://sourceforge.net/projects/saprfc/files/`

Then, I added the DLL files (php_saprfc_528.dll and php_saprfc_530.dll) to PHP extensions folder, then I updated php.ini file. When I start Apache server, the following error message shows to me

> PHP Startup: saprfc: Unable to initialize module
>
> Module compiled with module API=20060613
>
> PHP compiled with module API=20121212
>
> These options need to match

Googling this issue, I found that that saprfc was compiled with another version of PHP not same as the one I'm using. I'm running PHP 5.5.9, so I started looking with saprfc dll file compatible with PHP 5.5, but I couldn't find.

Can anybody please provide the download for the php_saprfc.dll which will work with PHP 5.5, or what are the steps for compiling php_saprfc.dll that will make it compatible with PHP 5.5?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compiled php module you can download here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/saprfcsapnwrfc/files/?source=navbar

Comment: Ah good suggestion. I see that project's binary downloads include modules for PHP 5.5 and 5.6 and the RFC library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the RFC DLL on the system in question? At runtime the SAPRFC PHP module needs it - from the [installation instructions](http://saprfc.sourceforge.net/src/INSTALL) (As you mentioned *DLL* I'm assuming you're using Windows):

> For installation (from binary package):
>
> - PHP binaries (http://www.php.net/downloads.php)
> - librfc32.dll in Windows System directory (or SAPGUI installed)

You can obtain `librfc32.dll` from a system that has SAPGUI installed (check the Windows directory) or by installing the classic RFC SDK. For more information on that SDK, see note [27517](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/27517) (SAP SMP login required).

Once you've done that and if the PHP module still doesn't work, then you can consider recompiling. See the instructions in that same installation guide for  instructions. They do mention Visual C 6.0 though, which is rather old...